# I changed the port to 9009 but still the Tomcat starts on 8084. Why is this?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7, server.xml

I edited the `server.xml` file of the tomcat (V:7) and changed the port to `9009` :

```
    <Connector port="9009" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But still when I start the server,it starts on `8084`. Why is that ? Did I edit the wrong thing ?

Let me notify that earlier the port value was = `8080` !. So the matter could be different.

But I have another version of tomcat installed (V:6).In that I have edited the file as :

```
<Connector port="7172" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

In this case the server runs on port : 7172. In this case it seems to be fine.

What is the matter with the former case ?

Comment: Did you start your Tomcat from some IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: @tomi yeah ! I started the first one from netbeans

Comment: Try to change port in Tomcat configuration in Netbeans

Comment: If you accept more answers I think your Tomcat server will work better :)

Comment: @tomi include this in your answer. It also solved the username and password problem ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

kill your server then run netstat or equivalent to check if the port you need is not used before assigning it to tomcat.